# Using scanf in Objective-C will not assign to an integer?

Tags: objective-c

I know that i need to assign `int a` and `int b` to something but i replaced it with the `scanf` functions example ( `int a = scanf("%d", a);` and `int b = scanf("%d", b);` but that did not work so i kept it as original like shown.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int a ;
    int b ;
    int c = a * b;

    printf("Welcome to the multiplication calculator");
    printf("\n");
    printf("what would you like to choose for first value?");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\n");
    printf("What would you like to input for the second value?");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf(" Here is your product");
    printf("\n");
    NSLog(@"a * b =%i", c);     

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int c = a * b;
```

Should be right before your NSLog.

When you say `int c = a * b` at the beginning here is what happens:

Since int a is not initialized, it is given a random garbage value, same with b. Then you immediately assign c the product of the two garbage values.

Comment: okay thank you guys mucho!! starting cs next year so i thought i would actually spend this summer working stuff out

Answer (score 1):

While you'r initializing c as c=a+b at that time the values of a and b are zeros so its storing c to zero. After that by using scanf your reading values to a and b . Now if you print c value the value is zero thats what it is showing.
    If you want proper result you have to put the statement c=a+b after reading a and b.

Comment: `a` and `b` aren't initialized to 0; they get garbage values from wherever they happen to be created in memory.